# How calculate the total price of a product attribute

Tags: python, django

```
class attributes(models.Model):

        attribute_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, db_index = True)
        price_update = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, 
                                       decimal_places = 2)


class Product(models.Model):

        attribute = models.ManyToManyField(attributes)
```

Comment: Well, there are some models. What exactly is your question?

Comment: A attribute has many price_update objects. I want to calculate the total price_update value for every product.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Product.objects.filter(id=product_id).aggregate(Sum('attribute__price_update'))
```

Comment: If the OP wants the sum for every product in a queryset, then `annotate` is more suitable than `aggregate`.

Comment: Do you tell me what is the views I write for this calculations